# Existence of a Certain Transport Map

Tags: measure-theory, optimal-transport

Let $(X,d)$ be a Polish space. Let
$$
\mu = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n \delta_{x_n},
$$ 
where $x_n \in X, a_n \in [0,1]$ and 
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n =1.
$$
Let 
$$
\nu = \sum_{k=1}^N b_k \delta_{x_k},
$$
with $b_n \in [0,1]$ and 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N b_n =1.
$$

Does there exits a map $T: X \to X $ such that
$$
\mu \circ T^{-1} = \nu.
$$

This claim comes up in the article https://www.lpsm.paris/pageperso/bolley/wasserstein.pdf, and there is an explanation there, but I am not too familiar with optimal transport language.

Comment: Where exactly did you find this claim? I don't think it is true as stated. For example, there is no transport map from $\delta_x$ to $\frac1 2 \delta_x+\frac 1 2\delta_y$ if $x\neq y$.

Comment: In the article on page 3: 'Morover one can transport $\mu_1$ onto $\mu_2$ by keeping ... '

Comment: But 1) these are not arbitrary sequences of numbers, they obey some additional conditions, and 2) the author does not claim the existence of a transport map, only of a transport plan. The construction of the transport plan is described in the article, but if you are only interested in existence, you can simply take the product measure.

Comment: Thank you, is a transport plan a coupling of the measures? Do you understand the description in the article? Like I said, im not familiar with the language used. What is a transport of $\mu_1$ onto $\mu_2,$ thank you.

Comment: Yes, a transport plan is the same as a coupling of measures (although some authors only use the latter term only for random variables and not there laws). Do you want an explanation for the cupling descrobed in the article. If so, you might consider changing your question to reflect that.